# Natural Language Processing and Keyword finding for Java

Tags: java, nlp

Assume we have a forum where a user can create topics and discuss about things. It is in my interest that the forum is serious and does not contain exchange of illegal things or organization of illegal meetings e.g. drug trade or child pornography. My application is written in Java, is there a Framework or an WebApi that can find and identify words or semantic meanings of the things user wrote to check  there are no illegal things going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually there are some blacklists of words that can be used.

If you want to apply NLP to it, you can use [Apache OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/) for basic NLP tasks such as tokenizing and POS detection.

From the POS tagging you may be able to apply word filters based on a blacklist. However, you'll have to deal with slangs and synonyms.

For the Slang/Synonym part you could use Conceptnet, where there's a WebAPI based on wikipedia. Take for instance the [link for "marijuana"](http://conceptnet.io/c/en/marijuana) and [link for "child pornography"](http://conceptnet.io/c/en/child_pornography) in Conceptnet- you could search for the relations of the input terms in your plataform to see if there's a link to "illegal drugs" or "child pornography". And then negate them,

In fact, I'd rather classify your problem as a NLU problem (it has to deal with the understanding of a text, not only its representation).